# Will I lose Elective Monarchy if I switch to Limited Council Authority as a Muslim?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

As in the title, I currently have Elective Monarchy as a Muslim Sultan and am wondering whether my succession law will automatically change to Open if I switch to Limited Council Authority.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Law will remain Elective unless you change it manually to open. From the [CK2 Wiki](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Succession):

> If Muslim or Eastern, (or Bön???) must have Conclave DLC and the
>   council law "full council authority" to enact elective succession.
>   **However, elective succession does not become invalid after you revoke council authority, so the law will not revert after
>   succession.**